# NodeJS and mysql ConnectionPool with local and remote applications

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-design, connection-pooling, distributed

Lately I have been researching on how to use pooling connections.

Firstly, just to put myself into the context, the way I see it pooling is used in order to not create new connections when you want to make a query but use the ones that you have available. The only time you create a new connection is when all your current connections are used.

I have managed to figure out how I am creating a pool, how I am requesting a connection and how and when to release the connection.

I am still confused about two aspects:

1. Am I right on saying that I should close the pool only when the server stops or crashes ? Compared to a simple use of mysql connections I do not need to close the pool after each database connection of any client to my app (this will work against the pool purpose ...). I want to make sure I am not confused.
2. My architecture includes two applications connecting on a single database. One is on the same host with the database and the other one is remote. What will be the effect on my performance if I create two pools for each application ? How does this affect my decision on picking an optimal connection limit for each pool ? If with a single app I use a connLimit of 100 should I use 50-50 with two applications ? In general, how do you pick a connLimit ?

Thank you very much for your time. I am just looking for some guidance in this as I have never design something similar.

Comment: MySQL _usually_ works fine without any kind of pooling.  Suggest you wait until you need it.

Comment: I have already started to re-write part of my back-end. I am still curious on how this would be done by other people.

Comment: How many different _threads_ might be connecting at the same time?

Comment: Two threads, one local and one remotely.

Comment: KISS - Ignore (or turn off) connection pooling.  Come back if you have an issue.